# Showing function is not independent

Tags: probability-distributions, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

[image]

I need to show that this is not independent, I found that $f(x,y) = 1$ with the given restrictions on $x$ and $y$, but now to find the marginal density functions, would the integral for finding $f_x(x)$ be from $0$ to infinity and the same for $f_y(y)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $f_X(x)=\int_x^{\infty} f(x,y) dy$ and $f_Y(y)=\int_0^{y} f(x,y) dx$. Calculate these simple intergals. $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff $f(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$.

Comment: why is the marginal probability of y from 0 to y? Shouldn't it be 0 to infinity?

Comment: @LearningMath899 Becasue the joint density $f(x,y)$ is $0$ when $x>y$. So even if you write $0$ to $\infty$ you will get $o$ for the integral from $y$ to $\infty$.

Comment: so they are equivalent?

Comment: @LearningMath899 If you write $0$ to $\infty$ it would be a mistake to use the expression $f(x,y)=0.0004e^{-0.03x-0.05y}$ for all $x$ because you are supposed to enter $f(x,y)=0$ fro $x >y$.

Comment: I don't quite understand, so the way this was done in lecture to find f(x,y) was that we took the bounds of x as 0 to infinity and y as x to infinity , now my question is when finding marginal probabilities I understand the x to infinity bound but not the 0 to y

Comment: @LearningMath899 $0<x<\infty,0<y<\infty$ and $x<y<\infty$ if and only if $0<x<\infty, 0 <y <\infty$ and $0< x <y$.

Comment: So the reason we took the upper bound of the marginal probability of y with respect to x is because y>x and x < infinity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111383/discussion-between-kavi-rama-murthy-and-learningmath899).

Comment: I have added my comments in the discussion.